# Which table to specify in this update?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that are identical in structure. `Table1` holds moderated data, `table2` holds the rest.

**Table 1**

```
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "id" | "name" | "description" | "type" | "country" |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "5"  | "a"    | "x"           | "1"    | "US"      |
| "6"  | "b"    | "x"           | "1"    | "UK"      |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+
| "id" |  orgId    |  "name"   |  "description"  | "type" | "country" | "status" |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+
| "1"  |   "5"     | "Title 1" | "Description 1" | "1"    | "US"      | "2"      |
| "2"  |   "6"     | "Title 2" | "Description 2" | "1 "   | "UK"      | "2"      |
| "3"  |   "6"     | "Title 2" | "Description 2" | "1 "   | "UK"      | "2"      |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

I run the below sql in order to update `table 1` with data from `table 2`, and it works well. What they actually are, are edits users have suggested for different titles and descriptions. So there may be more than one with the same `orgId`

```
UPDATE table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.name = b.name,
a.description = b.description
WHERE a.id=1; // Problem lies here
```

My problem is, I get only `table2`'s `id`,`type` and `country` in my script, which I then pass to a function that contains the above sql.

Now, which table should I specify in the `WHERE` clause there? Should it be `a ~ table1` or `b ~ table2`. Right now its `a`, but I don't get the value of `a.id` in my query string, and I can't use `orgId`, since there's more than one in there. Also, getting it thru in the querystring will take a lot more code and changes to several things.

Will it be ok if i used

```
 UPDATE table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b
    ON a.id = b.id
    SET a.name = b.name,
    a.description = b.description
    WHERE b.id=3; // Can I specify id from b here
```

I tried this and it works, but is this the right thing to do?

Comment: Yes, it is the right thing to do.

Comment: Yes. You can, and it is.

Comment: If you have a possible solution, how about you Try It Out yourself?  Create some test tables and give it a go.

Comment: Why do you have two separate tables, rather than a single one with a boolean `moderated` flag column?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to use id from either table as they are used to join. You could even use same id from table2 as follows:

```
 UPDATE table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b
    ON a.id = b.id
    SET a.name = b.name,
    a.description = b.description
    WHERE a.id=3; // note a.id, it is safe to use a.id for the passed id as it is been used to join two tables.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly fine. The join ensures that you get the right data.

Because of this...

```
ON a.id = b.id
```

You can use `a.id = 3` or `b.id = 3` in the `WHERE` clause